# Why am I getting the following error Children: duplicate children added: parent = HBox@1f28a595

Tags: java

As far as I can tell there is no repeated elements being added to the pane. Is it because they are the same object but different pictures? Here is the code:

```
    b2.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle( ActionEvent event ) {

            hboxCenter.getChildren().removeAll();
            hboxCenter.getChildren().addAll( ws.set.get( index ).getPicImage(), ws.set.get( index ).getInfoImage() );


        }});
```